# String that has an xaml element form from C# to XAML code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to pass an textBlock that contains a hyperlink. Something like this:

```html
 string textblock = "<TextBlock>Hello<Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://google.com"RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">Click</Hyperlink></TextBlock>"
```

i want to pass that string into the grid without using instances of objects. i read smth about xaml reader, loader but i cant figure it out...

my xaml looks like this:

```html
      <Window x:Class="DailyText.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="any" Height="450" Width="800" >
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: Even using XamlParser would create an object that you would have to add to the Children collection of the Grid. You should simply create a TextBlock and assign a Hyperlink to its Inlines.

Comment: Thank you. But you nou how should I add that object created by XamlParser to Children collection of the grid?

Answer (score 2):

Try to see if the code below fits your needs.

Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
        <TextBlock Name="TextBlockWithHyperlink" Background="Orange" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
          Hello
            <Hyperlink   NavigateUri="https://google.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                Click
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
      Hyperlink link=new Hyperlink() { NavigateUri=new Uri("https://google.com") };
      link.Inlines.Add("click");
      link.RequestNavigate+= Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
      tb.Inlines.Add("Hello");
      tb.Inlines.Add(link);
      tb.Height=60;
      tb.Background=Brushes.LightSeaGreen;
      tb.HorizontalAlignment= HorizontalAlignment.Center; 
      grid.Children.Add(tb);
    }

    private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
    }

  }
```

Comment: thank you for the help... but it doesnt help me... i scrape some text that contains hyperlinks and i cant handle it like that... i scrape the innerHtml and convert to xaml and then i want to push it to the grid